# I can't pass a variable from my PHP file to my Smarty file

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

```
public function hookDisplaySlider() {
    $this->context->smarty->assign('test', "test");
   // $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'slider';
   // $result = Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql);
   // $this->context->smarty->assign('query_results', Db::getInstance()->getValue($result));

  return $this->display(__FILE__,'views\templates\hook\dplus_slider.tpl');
}
```

my Smarty file:

```
<p>{$test}</p>
```

My tpl file correctly reads the html code but not the variables that I can place in it

Comment: My eror in "(1/1) ContextErrorException
Notice: Undefined index: test"

Comment: Hi, Please read how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and improve your question so the community can easily help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
         'test' => "test"
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object of smarty and then use this object to pass values.

Like -

```
require_once('Smarty/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->assign("test", 'test');
```

Note - Please provide proper path to require_once.